# Visual Studio 2013 loses data connections I added

Tags: visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

I haven't been able to determine a pattern, but I keep losing data connections I've added in the Server Explorer.

I have a set of about 20-25 databases I connect with regularly, so I set them up in the server explorer so I don't have to do it each time I open the IDE.

How can I either prevent this loss, or automatically re-add them so I don't have to manually do this every time VS loses them?

Comment: This has happened to me in 2013 twice now. Getting to be painful adding these back.

Comment: This is happening to me every time now that I've updated VS2013 to Update 4. I have tried the information in the answer below, but every time I start VS, with a project or not, it overwrites the DevaultView.SEView file without my entries. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I am experiencing the same now that I have Update 4. Followed answer below prior to update, but now I am back to adding them all manually. Seems update 4 has broken this work-around :/.

Comment: And here we are years later, still a problem for me in VS2017 - it fails both to pick up connections declared in my Linq to Sql designer, _and_ forgets connections I've added manually :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't remember where I found the information (I'm pretty sure it was stackoverflow, though) but here is what I have done.

1. I open Visual Studio with no project.
2. Go to server explorer and add the databases
3. CD to C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ServerExplorer
4. Make a copy of the file DefaultView.SEView
5. Then, if ever I lose any, I can just copy my backup over the DefaultView.SEView file and they are all back.

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent to UPDATE 4, the SEView file must be recreated, then backed up again as above. Still not sure why the file gets lost when it does.